# How do I solve this error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am getting an error for the line that starts with "Hi" and tips?

```
 // create header index map
  var headerIndexes = indexifyHeaders(headers);
  
  allData.forEach(function(row,i) {
    if (!row[headerIndexes["Status"]]) {
      var   htmlBody = 
          "Hi " + row[headerIndexes["Email Address"]] +",

" +
          "Thanks for filling out the Grade Check Request.

" +
            "Your choice:

" +
```

Comment: You have an extra `+` at the end.

Comment: `""` are also not expected to be multi-lined.  For multiline strings you should use template literals.

Answer (score 0):

```
var headerIndexes = indexifyHeaders(headers);
allData.forEach(function (row, i) {
  if (!row[headerIndexes["Status"]]) {
    var htmlBody = "Hi " + row[headerIndexes["Email Address"]] + "," + "Thanks for filling out the Grade Check Request." + "Your choice:"
  }
})
```